# Translating : optimization using derivative problem (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Regards, I have difficulty in translating this problem below.

**Problem :**

The operating cost of a certain truck is $25 - \frac{v}{4}$ cents/mile, if the truck travels with speed $v$ miles/hour. In addition, the driver gets $\$ 12 $ per hour. In a 400 miles run, what is the economical speed? with the speed must be between $40$ and $55$ miles/hour.

**(attempted) Solution :**

The total cost (in this 400 miles run) would be the operating cost + the driver's fee. I may *convert the costs to dollars*. Let $T(v)$ be the total cost, $O(v)$ be the operating cost, and $F(v)$ be the driver's fee if the truck travels at speed $v$ (miles/h) :
$$T(v) = O(v) + F(v)  $$
in 400 miles run, the $O(v)$ is 
$$ O(v) = (0.01)(400)(25 - \frac{v}{4}) $$
Now the time it takes for 400 miles run with speed $v$ is : $\frac{400}{v}$ hours
so the driver's fee is
$$ F(v) = 12\frac{400}{v} $$
now we have 
$$ T(v) = 100 - v + \frac{4800}{v} (\text{in \$ }) $$

To find the optimum value, we first find the $T'$ as
$$  T'(v)= -1 - \frac{4800}{v^{2}} $$
which has ***no stationary critical point.*** This means $v=55$ is the most economical one.

Is this correct, or am I missing something in translation..? Thanks.

Comment: Both operating costs and fixed costs are modelled as decreasing with speed, so the faster the better!

Comment: Thanks, @Macavity . I was suspicious because this problem is from application of derivative chapter. I presume it must have at least one stationary critical point.